# Make application quit Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hey guys I'm trying to make a function that quit my application when onClick on a Button but it doesn't work.
Would you take a look and let me now what's wrong with the code please ?
Here is the code :

```
public void addListenerOnButtonLeave()
{

    quitButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.quitButton);
    quitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    });
}
```

I put this function into the overrided onCreate(). 
Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Application or activity?  FOr activity, just call finish.  For Application-  there unfortunately doesn't seem to be a good way.

Comment: Quit button is your Button or Image view ?

Comment: Have you tried to don't call moveTaskToBack(true)?

Comment: What do you mean by **I put this function into the overrided onCreate()**. You can't have method inside method. Move it out.

Comment: Just call finish() in function.

Comment: it does work if I put only finish().
I think that it doesn't kill the processus but it put it in the background.
Thanks guys for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You may also use [`finishActivity (int requestCode)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishActivity(int))

> Force finish another activity that you had previously started with
>   startActivityForResult(Intent, int).

Answer (score -1):

Probably some of your activities are running in background. When you have switched between activities, you have not finished them.

First finish those activities by adding

```
ActivityName.this.finish()
```

just before you sail to another activity, and then use

```
getActivity().finish();
System.exit(0);
```

to quit the app triggered where needed.

Comment: Please mention the reasoning for which the answer has been downvoted so that it can be refined.